# How to show more bubble sizes in legend of ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a bubble plot using ggplot with different sized dots based on a vector of values. It works as it should with this code

```
ggplot(example, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=size))
```

However, the sample size legend only shows two values that are on the higher end of the size spectrum, even though in the example of http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_point.html it shows 4 dot sizes by default. I want to have a wider range of dot sizes in the legend.

I tried it with

```
example$size_bin <- cut(example$size, breaks = c(0,1000,5000,10000,50000,100000,300000),
                               labels=c("0-1000","1000-5000","5000-10000","10000-50000","50000-100000",">100000"))
ggplot(example, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=size_bin))
```

but because this is not a continuous scale this does not work. How can I change the legend so that  there are more sizes shown?

[image]

Comment: You may have to adjust the legend directly. I vaguely remember doing this, but don't have access to this code at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `breaks` argument in a separate `scale_size_continuous()` specification.  From `?scale_size_continuous`:

> breaks: One of:
>
> • ‘NULL’ for no breaks
>   • ‘waiver()’ for the default breaks computed by the transformation object
>   • A numeric vector of positions
>   • A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output

Comment: `breaks` will, unless you do something special, only show sizes within the range of the data. You may also need to set the `limits` argument larger to encompass a wider range